# Can ROG Zephyrus S GX701 cost 400$?

Tags: laptop

I found 2 prices. [Here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07M9SN4CD) and [here](https://m.alibaba.com/product/62221008550/NEW-2019-RTX-2080-gaming-laptop.html?tracelog=null) and I wonder how such laptop can be available for such price. Is this would come defected/fake specs. I noticed that goods from China are much cheaper but didn't think that difference can be such huge. Maybe I miss something.

Comment: If it's too good to be true, it's fake. And it looks fake, just the RTX would cost +$1000

Comment: So fake, lol....

Comment: It's like Wish, never believe in the specs they give if the price is too far off. Knowing Alibaba, if they ever send you one it'll either be older tech, or even worse: just the box.